# What creatures copy themselves?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I found the [dopplerat](https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/monsters-by-type/monstrosities/doppelrat-3pp/) which is perfect, but it's from a 3rd party book.

The only official creature I can find that does anything like this is the black pudding with its **split** rule.

Are there any creatures from any WoTC published material that have a similar ability to copy themselves?

- The copying needs to be at combat speed similar to the black pudding example.
- The copies will need to have turns, take actions and be target-able. Really a full creature in itself.
- I am specifically not looking for illusions that just cause attacks to miss like the **mirror image** spell.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail as to what you are looking for here. Worried that the broadness is going to lead to a list that isn't actually relevant.

Comment: Is an Arch Mage (Monster Manual NPC with spells up to level 9) who casts *simularcum* a violation of your criteria? (The DM would have to slightly modify the spells assigned to the CR 12 NPC to get that spell, so that may also violate your criteria ... a little more detail would be helpful here on what puts something out of bounds)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast has to be 100% by the book, no gm fiat at all, RAW only.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, but what's written in the MM **is** RAW.  You might want to say "just what is already printed" or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

#### Jellies and Puddings.

You mentioned the black pudding in your question, and there are several variants of puddings, as well as several variants of jelly. These all have the ability Split:

> **Split.** When a jelly that is Medium or larger is subjected to lightning or slashing damage, it splits into two new jellies if it has at least 10 hit points. Each new jelly has hit points equal to half the original jelly's, rounded down. New jellies are one size smaller than the original jelly.

#### Honorable Mention: Hydra heads

Okay, so a hydra is a single creature. But its heads behave like they are individual creatures. Each gets its own attack and its own reaction. And here's the relevant part:

> At the end of its turn, it grows two heads for each of its heads that died since its last turn, unless it has taken fire damage since its last turn. The hydra regains 10 hit points for each head regrown in this way.

Each head you kill produces two new heads, which is pretty similar to what you're looking for.

#### Too Slow: Any creature who can cast *Simulacrum*.

Currently, there is only one printed monster statblock containing the spell *simulacrum*, and that is [Manshoon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/manshoon) from *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*. Note, this may not be quite what you're looking for, *it takes 12 hours to cast*.  Alternatively, the rules do give guidance to the *Dungeon Master* for swapping spells out, so any creature that can cast 7th level spells could be given *simulacrum* according to [this guidance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#SpellSwaps):

> **Spell Swaps**
> One way to customize an NPC spellcaster is to replace one or more of its spells. You can substitute any spell on the NPC's spell list with a different spell of the same level from the same spell list. Swapping spells in this manner doesn't alter an NPC's challenge rating.

While this is a DM fiat type of ruling, it is one that is explicitly spelled out in the rules.

#### *Simulacrum* part II: *Wish* Boogaloo

Now, supposing a spellcaster with a 9th level spell slot were given *wish* by the DM in accordance with the guidance cited in the last section, then said caster could use *wish* to cast *simulacrum* as an action.

For a printed example, we have the Mad Mage himself, [Halaster Blackcloak](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/halaster-blackcloak).

Comment: Also the *Clone* spell, which is kinda like *Simulacrum* but different and also more expensive.

Answer (score 5):

### Undead raising more Undead

A number of undead can raise more undead (generally from slain humanoids). Most of these raise weaker undead than themselves, but there are a few exeptions:

- [Husk Zombies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/husk-zombie) (*Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*, pg. 293) raise more Husk Zombies when killed in melee:

  > **Curse of the Husk.** A humanoid slain by a melee attack from the zombie revives as a husk zombie on its next turn.
- Creatures killed by [shadows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shadow) Strength Drain attack are raises as new shadows:

  > If a non-evil humanoid dies from this attack, a new shadow rises from the corpse 1d4 hours later.

  Unfortunately, this copying is too slow to affect combat.

Answer (score 3):

### Devils and Demons using the variant "Summoning" rules.

It doesn't always work, but many Devils and Demons have the option of trying to summon a copy of themselves (or a swarm of lesser fiends).